# Destructuring Complex Object

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

Thanks so much for all the help with this answer you guys!! I'm very new to coding in general and you are making it a lot easier to get a grip on things! So far, I've got updated code kind of based on what I saw here (I didn't want to just copy & paste the answer, I wanted to learn everything that was happening with the code). From what I have now, the only thing I'm having trouble with is removing the "undefined" result from the output.  I'm assuming this has something to do with an "if" statement inside the "for" loop, but I wasn't sure. Any insights?

```js
let userList = {
  "people": [

    {
      firstName: "Fred",
      lastName: "Smith",
      dateOfBirth: 1980,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "Spanish",
        intermediate: "Chinese"
      }
    },

    {
      firstName: "Monica",
      lastName: "Taylor",
      dateOfBirth: 1975,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "Spanish",
        fluent: "English",
        intermediate: "French"
      }
    },

    {
      firstName: "Maurice",
      lastName: "Edelson",
      dateOfBirth: 1992,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "Spanish",
      }
    },

    {
      firstName: "Kelly",
      lastName: "Lang",
      dateOfBirth: 1982,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "German",
        intermediate: "Dutch"
      }
    }
  ]
};

for (var i = 0; i < userList.people.length; i++) {

  let table = document.getElementById("info");
  let newRow = table.insertRow(1);
  let cell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let dobCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
  let langs = newRow.insertCell(2);
  let {
    firstName
  } = userList.people[i];
  let {
    lastName
  } = userList.people[i];
  let {
    dateOfBirth
  } = userList.people[i];
  let {
    spokenLanguages: {
      native,
      fluent,
      intermediate
    }
  } = userList.people[i];
  cell.innerHTML += firstName + ' ' + lastName + "<br/>";
  dobCell.innerHTML += dateOfBirth + "<br/>";
  langs.innerHTML += native + ', ' + fluent + ', ' + intermediate + "<br/><br/>";

}
```

```css
  th {
    border: 6 px solid blue;
    border - collapse: collapse;
  }

table {
  border - collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 6 px solid black;
  border - collapse: collapse;
```

```html
<div id="show">

  <table id="info">

    <tr>
      <th><strong>First/Last Name</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Date of Birth</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Spoken Languages</strong></th>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `if` statement you are referring to?

Comment: you realise you can `let {a, b, c, d} = o` ... i.e. all those individual destructring can be done in one statement

Comment: which "output" is `undefined`?

Comment: if you're using complex things, why not `userList.people.forEach(person => { ... })` so you don't need to constantly reach into `userList.people[i]`? And then you don't even really need to destructure, you can just do ```cell.textContent = `${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}` etc. Also: don't use `.innerHTML` - you're setting text, so set `.textContent`, and don't use `<br>` to effect spacing: use CSS for that.

Comment: the undefined is because Maurice Edelson has no `intermediate`

Answer (score 3):

`intermediate` has no value for one of the person on the list. It is by default set to `undefined` if the property is missing.

You can define a default value as part of the destructuring assignment

```
let {
       spokenLanguages: {
          native = '',
          fluent = '',
          intermediate = ''
       }
    } = userList.people[i];
```

There are lots of ways to refactor the code to make it a bit more cleaner.

```js
let userList = {
  "people": [

    {
      firstName: "Fred",
      lastName: "Smith",
      dateOfBirth: 1980,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "Spanish",
        intermediate: "Chinese"
      }
    },

    {
      firstName: "Monica",
      lastName: "Taylor",
      dateOfBirth: 1975,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "Spanish",
        fluent: "English",
        intermediate: "French"
      }
    },

    {
      firstName: "Maurice",
      lastName: "Edelson",
      dateOfBirth: 1992,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "Spanish",
      }
    },

    {
      firstName: "Kelly",
      lastName: "Lang",
      dateOfBirth: 1982,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "German",
        intermediate: "Dutch"
      }
    }
  ]
};

for (var i = 0; i < userList.people.length; i++) {

  let table = document.getElementById("info");
  let newRow = table.insertRow(1);
  let cell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let dobCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
  let langs = newRow.insertCell(2);
  
  const {
    firstName = '',
    lastName = '',
    dateOfBirth = '',
    spokenLanguages: {
      native = '',
      fluent = '',
      intermediate = ''
    }
  } = userList.people[i];
  
  cell.textContent = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
  dobCell.textContent = dateOfBirth;
  langs.textContent = `${native}, ${fluent}, ${intermediate}`;

}
```

- As you are already using `es6`, you can rely on [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make your code more readable.
- For every iteration you are inserting a new row and cell, so you don't really need to use `+=` operator.

Comment: why not `let { firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, spokenLanguages: {
      native = '',
      fluent = '',
      intermediate = ''
    }
  } = userList.people[i];` to make the code even better :p

Comment: but you got rid of the defaults :p